# How to fix unrecognized argument that is not required? (Python)

Tags: python, parsing

When I run the following python argparse code, I get a argument parsing error:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                    prog='mix.py',
                    description='Mixing to generative models',
                    epilog="Example: python mix.py -a path/to/model_A.pth -b path/to/model_B.pth -w 0.3 -o my_mixed_model.pth will create a generator file my_mixed_model.pth which will mix voice A and B. w=0 --> 100 % A w=1 --> 100 % B")
                    
parser.add_argument('-a',metavar='',type=str, help='path to model A (ex. path/to/modelA/G_60000.pth)')  # path to voice A G_*****.pth
parser.add_argument('-b',metavar='',type=str, help='path to model B (ex. path/to/modelB/G_67000.pth)')  # path to voice B G_*****.pth
parser.add_argument('-w',metavar='', type=float, help='(float) relative weight: 0.0==voice_A, 1.0==voice_B')
parser.add_argument('o',metavar='', type=str, help='output model (ex. out.pth)' ) # path to output mixed model
args=parser.parse_args()
```

This is the error:

```
usage: mix.py [-h] [-a] [-b] [-w]
mix.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

I do not understand why unrecognized arguments: -f when -f is not a required argument. Even when I add an -f argument, like so:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                    prog='mix.py',
                    description='Mixing to generative models',
                    epilog="Example: python mix.py -a path/to/model_A.pth -b path/to/model_B.pth -w 0.3 -o my_mixed_model.pth")# will create a generator file my_mixed_model.pth which will mix voice A and B. w=0 --> 100 % A w=1 --> 100 % B

parser.add_argument('-a',metavar='',type=str, help='path to model A (ex. path/to/modelA/G_60000.pth)')  # path to voice A G_*****.pth
parser.add_argument('-b',metavar='',type=str, help='path to model B (ex. path/to/modelB/G_67000.pth)')  # path to voice B G_*****.pth
parser.add_argument('-w',metavar='', type=float, help='(float) relative weight: 0.0==voice_A, 1.0==voice_B')
parser.add_argument("-f", required=False)
parser.add_argument('o',metavar='', type=str, help='output model (ex. out.pth)' ) # path to output mixed model
args=parser.parse_args()
```

I still get the following error:

```
usage: mix.py [-h] [-a] [-b] [-w] [-f F]
mix.py: error: the following arguments are required: 

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

This is how I am calling the script:

```
python mix.py -a SP_A/logs/44k/G_64000.pth -b SP_B/logs/44k/G_60000.pth -w 0.5 out.pth
svc infer -n 1 -a -fm crepe -m out.pth -c SP_A/configs/44k/config.json input.wav -o output_50.wav
```

How should I write the argsparse code?

Comment: Show how you're calling the script.

Comment: The error is happening because you're using the `-f` option when you run the script, but it doesn't want that argument. Why are you doing that?

Comment: If you don't specify `action='store_true'` for the `-f`, it's assumed to be one that takes a value after it. The second error is happening because you're passing `-f` without the required value.

Comment: @Barmar, I added the code that shows how I called the script.

In the original code, I do not call for -f, so I'm not sure why I am getting the unrecognized arguments: -f .

Comment: There's no `-f` argument on the `python mix.py` line, I don't see why you would get that error. Is `svc infer` on the next line or the same line?

Comment: @Barmar svc infer is on a new line

Comment: What's happening seems like the two lines are being combined when you try to execute it. How are you executing the commands?